# Rails Models Validates for JSON type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

в базе есть таблица с полем **info** тип **json**
пример записи в **info**

```
{
  a: '123',
  b: 'ABC',
  c: [
    {
      x: 'abc',
      y: 'abc123'
    },
    {
      x: 'abc',
      y: 'abc123'
    }
  ]
}
```

как можно в модели проверить валидность данных в **info**

```
info[:a] format with /\d{3}/ message = info: 'a invalid'
info[:b] format with /[A-Z]{3}/ message = info: 'b invalid'
info[:c].map do |s|
  s[:x] format with /[a-z]{3}/  message = info: 'c x invalid'
  s[:y] format with /[a-z]{3}\d{3}/ message = info: 'c y invalid'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, тут целый набор вариантов есть.

---

**Во-первых**, можно описать форму данных декларативно с помощью [JSON schema](https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema). Валидатор придётся писать самостоятельно, но его суть проста:

```
JSON::Validator.fully_validate(схема, значение)
```

...плюс закидывание результатов в `errors`.

Написав нормальный `EachValidator`, можно добиться аккуратного синтаксиса:

```
validates :info, json_schema: INFO_SCHEMA
```

У него, правда, сообщения об ошибках недружелюбны к пользователям, но весьма дружелюбны к разработчикам: показывают техническую суть ошибки в виде точного сообщения и пути в документе (ключи/индексы), где проблема обнаружена.

---

**Во-вторых**, всегда есть дубовый [`validate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate), где можно устроить вообще что угодно:

```
validate :info_format

def info_format
  info['c'].each_with_index |obj, i|
    unless obj['x'] =~ /[a-z]{3}/
      errors.add :info, "`c`'s #{ordinalize(i+1)} element's `x` is invalid"
    end
    # ...
  end
  errors.add :info, "`a` is invalid" unless info['a'] =~ /\d{3}/
  # ...
end
```

---

Валидации таких глубоких структур для пользователей обычно бесполезны, может, тут и вовсе стоит использовать **строгую** валидацию (методы с `!`), провал которой заканчивается исключением `StrictValidationFailed`, а не возвратом объекта с пояснениями.